# Get value from input tag and place value into a specific part of your html code

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to html, javascript and jquery

I have a question about grabbing values from inputs and displaying them specifically this:

```
<input name="meaty" style="height:25px; width:100px;" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Rate 1 - 10 " />
```

So I would like the user to input something and I would like that value that the user inputed to be shown on new page after clicking a button. So what I have is the users will fill out a bunch of input tags then they will press a button and a new page should pop up with all their inputs. Any tips would be great thanks!

Comment: if the data is not sensitive then you can pass data through querystring.

Comment: @Kartikeya Thanks! Could you give me an example?

Comment: see this:http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Send-Pass-Data-Values-from-one-page-to-another-using-jQuery.aspx

Comment: just visit the link provided above..it will solve your problem..

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of the input field you can use

```
var inputVal = $( "input[name='meaty']" ).val();
```

By new page I assume you mean a dom element that you will popup?

If not then you will have to pass this value through to the new page either via cookie/local storage or as parameters on the url.